# Can I add Microdata on generated content from CSS?

Tags: css, microdata

If I generate content with CSS can I still apply Microdata to it in the HTML?

Will Schema or RDFa accept an `alt` or `title` tag as a value?

```
h1:after,h2:after,h3:after,h4:after,h5:after,h6:after
    {content:attr(title);display:block;}  
h1:before,h2:before,h3:before,h4:before,h5:before,h6:before
    {content:attr(alt);display:block;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you mean by “schema markup”, the answer is “No.” Generated content is plain text and cannot contain any markup or have any markup associated with it.

Comment: Most probably he means microdata like RDFA or Schema.org. I think.